Option to enable the SHA-1 Signed JARs
I am Using  IBM WebSphere Liberty Version  23.0.0.6  .It contains in built in java "1.8.0_371".
From Oracle Java 18.0_351 onwards, they Disabled SHA-1 Signed JARs. But they gave below work around opion to enable the SHA-1 Signed JAR
Users can, at their own risk, remove these restrictions by modifying the java.security configuration file (or override it by using the java.security.properties system property) and removing "SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01" from the jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms security property and "SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01" from the jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms security property.
This work around is  working in  Plain Oracel Java 1.8.0_371.
But, this work around is not working in  Java 1.8.0_371, which part of the IBM WebSphere Liberty Version  23.0.0.6.
This the exception i'm receiving:

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider JsafeJCE


Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: file:/Lava/wlp/usr/servers/g7al85901f51.ihy.broadcom.net/apps/expanded/affwebservices.war/WEB-INF/lib/cryptoj.jar is not signed by a trusted signer.

Is there any equivalent work around to enable SHA-1 Signed JARs in IBM WebSphere Liberty Version  23.0.0.6

This isn't relevant to solving your problem, but IBM WebSphere Liberty doesn't include Oracle Java. This is just a question about Java, not about Liberty since the error is coming from Java, not Liberty.
